# Use TabLayout + ViewPager + Toolbar to implement this Material Design effect？

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design

Hi！I want to implement a swipe effect like this:

[sample from google material design](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1SkeVD6imJA_MwjipNR-DbNh1xw4au9yy%2F02-rally-tabs.mp4)

**I've thought about 3 ways:**

1. ActionMenuLayout + toolbar + ViewPager.
2. TabLayout + requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) + ViewPager.
3. TabLayout + Toolbar + ViewPager

**My Questions:**

1. I don't know which way is accessible.
2. I'm confused that how to make tabs displayed in toolbar.
3. How to implement the anime?

Could you help me?
Thank you

Comment: It seems to me tab layout and viewpager will do for it, give it a go!

Comment: I think you may use BottomNavigation https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#